# How to store raw jpeg image into the internal flash of STM32F2 series microcontroller using Embedded C?

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32

I have a .JPEG file which I need to store into internal memory of the STM32F2 series controller. Is this possible to do without any conversion/encoding the JPEG file? If so can anyone please provide some sample code for my understanding.

Comment: What microcontroller? Using what language? This is too broad.

Comment: Microcontroller : STM32F series, Language : C.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to tag such relevant facts, so that it's clear what you're asking, and people skilled in those topics can find the question.

Comment: Is the JPEG file a constant that you have at build time?  Or is it a variable that is produced at run time?

Comment: JPEG file is a constant, which will be available during build time.

Comment: a jpeg file is just bits and bytes, why are you struggling to put bits and bytes on the flash in a way your program can access?  there is no operating system so it is up to you to embed it into the application.

Comment: Hi @0412PA If this question has been solved by the answer please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, one method is to define a constant array which is initialized with the data from the JPEG (or any binary) file.  Then that array definition gets linked with your code and becomes a part of the firmware programmed to flash.  If desired, you can use linker directives to locate the array (i.e., the file data) at a specific address in flash.

You can accomplish this general idea in many different ways.  Below is just one specific example implementation of this technique.

First, create a desktop program that reads the JPEG file as a stream of bytes and writes those bytes into a new comma separated text file.  Here are the first two lines of an example file, I'll call `my_jpeg.h`:

```
0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x10, 0x4A, 0x46, 0x49, 0x46, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x48,
0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xE1, 0x03, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x69, 0x48, 0x00, 0x4D, 0x4D, 0x46,
```

Then define an array in your C code and initialize it with the data from the file you created.

```
const uint8_t my_jpeg[] = {
    #include "my_jpeg.h"
};
```

Now all that JPEG file data will be included in your firmware and be programmed to flash when you program the firmware.

You could use a makefile recipe or your IDE's pre-build batch script feature to run your JPEG conversion program automatically and produce `my_jpeg.h` during the build.